# How recurrsion works

Tags: c#-4.0

Hi I have a sample code here in which i am trying to shift the array by a given number of times.In output i want to print the final array generated after going through all the shifts.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] oldArray={1,2,3,4};
            int[] newArray=Program.shiftRight(oldArray,3);
           foreach(var item in newArray)
                 Console.Write(item+ " ");
        }

        public static int[] shiftRight(int[] arr,int times)
        {
            int[] demo = new int[arr.Length];

                for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
                {
                   demo[(i+1) % demo.Length] = arr[i];
                }
             foreach(var item in demo)
                 Console.Write(item+ " ");
            Console.WriteLine("");
            times--;
               if(times>0)
               {                       
                   shiftRight(demo,times);
               }
              Console.WriteLine("\n");
            return demo;

        }
```

The output i am getting is 
Hello, world!

```
4 1 2 3 
3 4 1 2 
2 3 4 1


4 1 2 3
```

can somebody explain why in main i am not getting  output as "2 3 4 1"
but "4 1 2 3"?Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you step through it with a debugger?

Comment: @Hans there is no try/catch block.